# External HDDs keep shutting down and starting up

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I have a Lenovo Y50 UHD running Windows 8.1 connected to three Seagate external HDDs.  Every time I want to grab a file, the HDDs take a moment to spin back up; this didn't happen when connected to my Dell Studio 1558 running Windows 7 a month ago.  Is there a Windows setting I need to change?  Does the fact that the new computer has USB3 slots change anything?  I assume some secret setting/"feature" that Microsoft added in Windows 8/8.1 to blame.

Comment: Not sure about 8.1, but on Win7 the setting is at Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings -> Change advanced power settings -> Hard disk -> Turn off hard disk after -> Setting:

Comment: Also in the Power Settings, make sure the "USB selected suspend setting" is disabled.